# Getting string content of the complex mixed element with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

For, example, there is an xml:

```
<article-list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="3.xsd">
    <article section="physics">
        Increasing linear dynamic range of commercial digital photocamera
        <author>M. V. Konnik</author>
        <content>
            Methods of increasing linear optical dynamic range
        </content>
    </article>
```

my aim is to query string content of `article` element. I.e.:

```
Increasing linear dynamic range of commercial digital photocamera
```

The obvious solution like this:

```
<!--xquery-->
{
for $article in doc("name.xml")//article-list/article
    where $article/receiving-date > xs:date("2005-01-01")
    return
        <article>
            {$article}
        </article>
}
```

Returns whole `article` tree, not only a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$article is an element, not a node. To get the text (the text you want is actually the text child node of the $article node), you just need:

```
 {$article/text()}
```